# Как настроить фильтрацию ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-filter, many-to-many

```
        if autosave_options:
            print(autosave_options)
            options_query = Q()
            option_list = []
            for autosave_option in autosave_options:
                if autosave_option.options_value:
                    print(autosave_option.options_value)
                    option_list.append(autosave_option.options_value.pk)
            if option_list:
                options_query &= Q(options__in=option_list)
            query &= options_query
```

Пытаюсь отфильтровать обьекты, но проблема фильтрует если совпадает одно значение, а мне нужно если все совпали. Например у товара есть много опций и мне нужно отфильтровать по определенным двум, трем и тд